# AS3 Isometric game Sorting Object Index

Tags: actionscript-3, logic

I am creating an isometric game, and I would like to know how to correctly position the (Z-index) of objects when the player goes behind them and infront of them.

I have been using

```
            if(y>stage.stageHeight/2){
                parent.setChildIndex(this,parent.getChildIndex(this)+1);
                gotoAndStop(2);

            } else if (y<stage.stageHeight/2){
                parent.setChildIndex(this,parent.getChildIndex(this)+1);
                gotoAndStop(1);
            }
```

So far yet I have been receiving this error

```
 RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
```

My logic for this is; "If the object is UNDER the player then move its index up so that it is over the player, but if the object is ABOVE the player, then decrease it's index so that is under the player."

Any ideas on how I could improve this code so that it works without giving me errors?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you're going to be swapping many objects it's best to work from outside the *object*. For example a **Level** class that contains an array of all your swappable objects. It will also be responsible for looping through each object and swapping it according to its **y** value.

```
public var objectArray:Array = [];

for (var ob1:Object in objectArray){
    for (var ob2:Object in objectArray){
        if(ob1 == ob2) continue;
        swap(ob1, ob2); 
    }
}

//...

public function swap(a:Object, b:Object):void {
    if (a.y > b.y != a.parent.getChildIndex(a) > b.parent.getChildIndex(b)) {
        a.parent.swapChildren(a, b);
    }
}
```

*Keep in mind this is not the most efficient way to do it, because you have to check each object against each other object **O(n^2)**.*

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep in mind that the index you provide is the index of the object in the container's children array. it cannot be less than zero and it cannot be more or equal to the actual childCount of the container.

so parent.getChildIndex(this)+1 is very unsafe

```
var nextIndex:int = parent.getChildIndex(this)+1;
if(nextIndex < parent.numChildren && nextIndex >= 0)
    parent.setChildIndex(this, nextIndex);
```